# What all basic android gui elements are available?

Tags: android, user-interface

I wanted to know the gui elements we have in android?
Can anyone show me a picture as well like how do these elements look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what the [ApiDemos](http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) sample application is for :-) You'll specifically want to check out the **Views > Controls** section for an activity that just shows common views.

To try out ApiDemos on an emulator or on your phone:

1. [Download the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and follow the instructions to get the SDKs for various platforms (1.5, 1.6, 2.0.1)
2. [Install Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (Eclipse Classic works)
3. [Install ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)
4. Create a new Android project from the `samples/ApiDemos` directory in any of the platform-version folders inside the SDK.
5. Hook up your phone via USB and turn on USB debugging in **Settings > Applications** (or turn on an emulator)
6. Build and run the ApiDemos project in Eclipse with your phone hooked up or your emulator running

There is also the [Hello, Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) set of tutorials, and that has some screenshots of views, as they look on older versions of Android.

Comment: +1 Agree with Roman.
There is no exhaustive list(AFAIK); you will have to read the documentation and the samples bundled.

Comment: Also check out http://www.droiddraw.org and the 'Widget Guide'. It's not up-to-date but it's a fairly good resource.